# Waiting for a counter to reach a value with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have a counter in a class that increments every time a button is pressed.

I would like, in the ngafterViewInit(), to wait for this counter to reach this value before continuing.
I tested like this

```
export class A implements AfterViewInit {
  private counter: number=0;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (this.counter == 8)
        resolve();
    }).then(() => console.log("Counter has reached the value"));
  }

  private onClick(index: number) {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

I tried by adding the counter value in a Subject, and subscribe the subject in the promise? It works, but it seems laborious to me.

Comment: From the example, I'd just add `if(this.counter >= 8) {...}` to `onClick`.

Comment: @GunnarB. I don't se your point... Why my promise would resolved with that?

Comment: I don't really see the point of needing the promise at all in the example. Effectively you just use it as an if, so I'd just put that into the `onClick`. The actual cycle of `ngAfterViewInit` is long gone when the counter reaches 8.

Comment: It's because I want to make asynchronous code... You cannot see it because i removed all my chained promises to be more clear. But with your solution, the "console.log("Counter has reached the value")" wouldn't wait for the counter. It's important that this console.log it is in a promise because I do operation in this then I CANNOT make in the "onClick" function.
I want to do thoses operations ONLY when the counter has reached the value, independetly from the onClick envent.

Comment: Well, you could also turn the counter into an observable structure and pipe/subscribe to that (with a filter for the value). Other than that, I don't think, you can do much differently than now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wonder how I exactly did :

```
private pointsCalibrated: number = 0;     
private pointsCalibratedListener: Subject<Number> = new Subject<any>();

        [...]

        .then(() => {
          this.startCalibrationFlag = !this.startCalibrationFlag;
          var promise: Promise<void> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var subscription: Subscription = this.pointsCalibratedListener.subscribe((counterValue) => {
              if (counterValue == NB_POINTS) {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
                resolve();
              }
            })
          });
          return promise;
        })

[...]

private onClick(index: number): void { 
    //doSomething
      this.pointsCalibratedListener.next(++this.pointsCalibrated);
    }
```